# Error using new socket.io functionality serverSideEmit (). Node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

> Error: this adapter does not support the serverSideEmit()
> functionality

Code:

```html
module.exports = (io) => {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('Usuario conectado');
        socket.on('prueba', (x) => {
            io.serverSideEmit('Prueba', 'Esto es una prueba');
        });
    });
    io.on('Prueba', (x) => {
        console.log(x);
    })
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Hi. Please add more details to your code, showing which adapter was used to create `io`. I assume this is the Redis one but it does not appear clearly.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that with the adapter?